# Failed to verify code signature for Xamarin Forms Hot Restart Provisioning feature in VS 2019

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am following [Look iOS Developer](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac/) and [Xamarin Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart?WT.mc_id=xamarin-c9-jamont) to run a newly created Xamarin Forms app in VS 2019 (latest version). After completing steps, I am unable to run the app in the device. I am getting Failed to verify code signature error.
I have newly created my App Developer Account and I can also see the certificate VS 2019 created for provisining in the app developer portal.

```
Unhandled Exception: Xamarin.iOS.Windows.WindowsiOSException: Failed to install the application: ApplicationVerificationFailed(3892346904) - Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.9VqxJr/extracted/Payload/App4.iOS.app : 
    0xe8008018 (The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.)
       at Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Installer.ApplicationSession.OnInstallProgressReport(IntPtr command, IntPtr status, IntPtr userData) in C:\A\_work\80\s\src\Tools\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Launcher\Installer\ApplicationSession.cs:line 324
    An error occurred while trying to deploy the app 'App4.iOS.app'. 
    Details: Error running hotrestart: 'An unexpected error occurred and the process has been terminated'. Command: 'deploy -u=fbffae2ce4c666b7fdb7d99f065bbd40cf4f83ad -i=com.companyname.App4 -n=App4.iOS.app'
    2>Deploy failed. The app 'App4.iOS.app' could not be deployed to the device 'Ab'. Please check the logs for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple restart did the trick.